# slack dev returns sdk_hook_invocation_failed

Tags: typescript, slack, deno, slack-commands

I try to run [hello-world slack template project](https://github.com/slack-samples/deno-hello-world) on my localhost, but it fails with an error:

```
$ slack dev
? Choose a local environment Install to a new workspace
? Pick a workspace for the app example-tech T01234NFT Not installed

 If you leave this workspace, you can no longer manage the installed apps
   Installed apps will belong to the workspace if you leave the workspace

Updating local app install for workspace "Tech"
error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: TS2339 [ERROR]: Property 'utime' does not exist on type 'typeof Deno'. 'Deno.utime' is an unstable API. Did you forget to run with the '--unstable' flag?
await Deno.utime(dest, statInfo.atime, statInfo.mtime);
               ~~~~~
at https://deno.land/std@0.67.0/fs/copy.ts:92:16
TS2339 [ERROR]: Property 'utimeSync' does not exist on type 'typeof Deno'. 'Deno.utimeSync' is an unstable API. Did you forget to run with the '--unstable' flag?
Deno.utimeSync(dest, statInfo.atime, statInfo.mtime);
         ~~~~~~~~~
at https://deno.land/std@0.67.0/fs/copy.ts:103:10
TS2339 [ERROR]: Property 'utime' does not exist on type 'typeof Deno'. 'Deno.utime' is an unstable API. Did you forget to run with the '--unstable' flag?
await Deno.utime(dest, statInfo.atime, statInfo.mtime);
               ~~~~~
at https://deno.land/std@0.67.0/fs/copy.ts:127:16
TS2339 [ERROR]: Property 'utimeSync' does not exist on type 'typeof Deno'. 'Deno.utimeSync' is an unstable API. Did you forget to run with the '--unstable' flag?
Deno.utimeSync(dest, statInfo.atime, statInfo.mtime);
         ~~~~~~~~~
at https://deno.land/std@0.67.0/fs/copy.ts:152:10
TS2339 [ERROR]: Property 'utime' does not exist on type 'typeof Deno'. 'Deno.utime' is an unstable API. Did you forget to run with the '--unstable' flag?
await Deno.utime(dest, srcStatInfo.atime, srcStatInfo.mtime);
               ~~~~~
at https://deno.land/std@0.67.0/fs/copy.ts:172:16
TS2339 [ERROR]: Property 'utimeSync' does not exist on type 'typeof Deno'. 'Deno.utimeSync' is an unstable API. Did you forget to run with the '--unstable' flag?
Deno.utimeSync(dest, srcStatInfo.atime, srcStatInfo.mtime);
         ~~~~~~~~~
at https://deno.land/std@0.67.0/fs/copy.ts:200:10
Found 6 errors.
const functionModule = await import(`file://${functionFilePath}`);
                         ^
at async getDefaultExport (https://deno.land/x/deno_slack_hooks@1.0.1/utilities.ts:27:26)
at async readImportedManifestFile (https://deno.land/x/deno_slack_hooks@1.0.1/get_manifest.ts:114:20)
at async getManifest (https://deno.land/x/deno_slack_hooks@1.0.1/get_manifest.ts:30:22)
at async getValidateAndCleanManifest (https://deno.land/x/deno_slack_hooks@1.0.1/get_manifest.ts:129:29)
at async https://deno.land/x/deno_slack_hooks@1.0.1/get_manifest.ts:136:26
Check /home/ms/.slack/logs/slack-debug-20230531.log for full error logs

 Error: Unable to get your app manifest details. Please check your manifest file: 
Command for 'GetManifest' returned an error: exit status 1 (sdk_hook_invocation_failed)

Suggestion:

Try to run `slack doctor` to check that your system dependencies are up-to-date.
```

Unfortunately `slack doctor` doesn't find any issues:

```
$ slack doctor

SYSTEM

    ✔ Operating System (resource allocation manager)
        Version: linux (amd64)

    ✔ Deno (a JavaScript runtime)
        Version: v1.20.6
        Recommendation: We suggest using the latest version of Deno

    ✔ Git (a version control system)
        Version: git version 2.34.1


SLACK

    ✔ CLI (this tool for building Slack apps)
        Version: 2.2.0

    ✔ Configurations (any adjustments to settings)
        Last updated: 2023-05-30 16:31:27 +02:00

    ✔ Credentials (your Slack authentication)
        Team domain: example-tech
        Team ID: T01234NFT
        User ID: U21234NFT
        Last updated: 2023-05-31 11:00:56 +02:00
        Token status: Valid


PROJECT

    ✔ Dependencies (requisites for development)
        deno_slack_hooks: 1.0.1
        deno_slack_sdk: 2.1.2
        deno_slack_api: 2.1.0

Errors: 0
```

Where's the problem?

Comment: Part of the error message that you posted: `'Deno.utime' is an unstable API. Did you forget to run with the '--unstable' flag?` Did you run (or [install](https://deno.com/manual@v1.34.1/tools/script_installer#script-installer)) the script using the argument [unstable](https://deno.com/manual@v1.34.1/basics/standard_library#troubleshooting)?

Comment: Actually it's a bit weird, cause you can not run this command with `--unstable` flag. When I tried I received: `Error: unknown flag: --unstable`